# TypeError: Cannot read property 'shet' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

There was an error that I don't know where it was wrong. I recently started writing code from YouTube. So I would like to have some advice on where I should fix it and make the code work.

```
    **code**

    function doGet() {
      

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("inded");
    }
function userClicked(data){
var url ="myurl";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName([data.shet]);
ws.appendRow([data.nb,data.kun,data.bath,data.tod,data.bon,data.lan,data.sam,data.ha]); 
}
```

The only information(nb,kun,bath,tod,bon,lan,sam,ha) I will enter is numbers. The 'shet' is the number of the sheet.

```
**html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>กรอกเลข</h1>
   <div>
   <label>ใบที่</label><input type="text" id="shet">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>ตัวเลข</label><input type="text" id="nb">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>คูณ กลับ</label><input type="text" id="kun">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>เต็ง บาท </label><input type="text" id="bath">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>โต๊ด</label><input type="text" id="tod">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>วิ่งบน</label><input type="text" id="bon">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>วิ่งล่าง</label><input type="text" id="lan">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>2ใน3</label><input type="text" id="sam">
   </div>
   <div>
   <label>2ใน5</label><input type="text" id="ha">
   </div>
   <div>
   <button id="btn"> บันทึกข้อมูล </button>
   </div>
   <script>
     document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", saveData);
     
     function saveData() {
     var data = {}
         data.shet = document.getElementById("shet").value;
         data.nb = document.getElementById("nb").value;
         data.kun = document.getElementById("kun").value;
         data.bath = document.getElementById("bath").value;
         data.tod = document.getElementById("tod").value;
         data.bon = document.getElementById("bon").value;
         data.lan = document.getElementById("lan").value;
         data.sam = document.getElementById("sam").value;
         data.ha = document.getElementById("ha").value;
     google.script.run.userClicked(data);
     document.getElementById("shet").value="";
     document.getElementById("nb").value="";
     document.getElementById("kun").value="";
     document.getElementById("bath").value="";
     document.getElementById("tod").value="";
     document.getElementById("bon").value="";
     document.getElementById("lan").value="";
     document.getElementById("sam").value="";
     document.getElementById("ha").value="";
     
     }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details about the steps to followed to execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

`userClicked` is supposed to run when the submit button in your HTML is clicked. In this case, the `data` you entered in your HTML `<input>` elements is passed as an argument. Instead, you're trying to execute `userClicked` directly from the script editor, so `data` is not passed as an argument: `data` is `undefined`, and hence the error you're getting.

#### Solution:

If you want to test this from your script editor, add some default data in case no `data` is passed as an argument. Something like this:

```
function userClicked(data) {
  if (!data) {
    var data = {};
    data.shet = 1;
    data.nb = "Whatever";
    // Rest of `data` properties
  }
  // Rest of your function
}
```

But keep in mind that this is supposed to be called from your HTML.

#### Other issues:

- If the submitted `shet` value is the name of the sheet you want to get, you should just remove the `[]` from `var ws = ss.getSheetByName([data.shet]);` ([getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) should receive a `String`), even though the data will probably be appended anyway to the sheet if you don't change anything.
- If the submitted `shet` value is a number corresponding to the `index` of your desired sheet, you should change that to `var ws = ss.getSheets()[data.shet];` (see [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)), but take into account that the `index` is 0-based.

#### Related:

- [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/)

Answer (score 0):

### Modification point:

- Your current solution is not looking for the number of the sheet.
- As you can see in the **.gs** file, you are asking for the name of
  the sheet:

  ```
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName([data.shet]);
  ```
- In order to **specify** the number of the sheet use [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) instead:

  ```
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[data.shet];
  ```

> It is important to mention that `ss.getSheets()` is an array of all
> the sheet objects in the spreadsheet file. To specify the first sheet
> (from left to right) the numbering starts from 0 and thus `ss.getSheets()[0]`. Therefore, in
> your webapp, if you want to interact with the **first** sheet, you
> need to pass **0** in the first field. If you want the **second** sheet
> then **1** etc..

---

### Solution:

Modify **only** the **.gs** code as follows:

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("inded");
}
function userClicked(data){
   var url ="myurl";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheets()[data.shet];
 ws.appendRow([data.nb,data.kun,data.bath,data.tod,data.bon,data.lan,data.sam,data.ha]); 
}
```

Keep the **inded.html** file as it is.

---

### Instructions (if applicable):

In case you haven't done it already, you need to **deploy** this project as a web app.

Please follow these steps:

1. Click on *Publish* => *Deploy as web app*

[image: deploy]

2. Click on **deploy** in the pop up window and **open** the newly created web app URL.

**Note** that if you have already deployed your web app, after you make the changes, you need to follow step 1 and then **update** the current project.